# Java replace if else with switch

Tags: java

I'm new in programming and need some help with Java.

I want to convert if else statements to switch. Can you help me? And also, what are the best ways to optimise that code? 
I want to learn the differences between statements and I got a lot of errors trying to do it another way...

```
    import java.util.Locale;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

        double num1, num2, out;
        int in = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

        if(in == 1) {
            if(args.length == 3) {
                out = num1 + num2;
                System.out.printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f\n", num1, num2, out);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("wrong number of arguments");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if(in == 2) {
            if(args.length == 3) {
                out = num1 - num2;
                System.out.printf("%.1f - %.1f = %.1f\n", num1, num2, out);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("wrong number of arguments");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if(in == 3) {
            if(args.length == 3) {
                out = num1*num2;
                System.out.printf("%.1f * %.1f = %.1f\n", num1, num2, out);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("wrong number of arguments");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if (in == 4) {
            if(args.length == 3) {
                out = num1/num2;
                System.out.printf("%.1f / %.1f = %.1f\n", num1, num2, out);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("wrong number of arguments");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if (in == 5){
            if(args.length >= 3) {
                double min = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
                int ind = 1;
                for(int i=1; i<args.length; i++) {
                    if(Double.parseDouble(args[i]) <= min) {
                        min = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
                        ind = i;
                    }
                } 
                System.out.print("minimum of numbers");
                for(int j=1; j<args.length; j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%s ", args[j]);
                }
                System.out.printf("is %s\n", args[ind]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("wrong number of arguments");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: At [docs.oracle...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is a good example how it works ;) You can use the offical doc's to find good examples and fit them to your code: eg. after `case 1:` add `{` to use more then one line of code and don't forget to close it^^

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `switch` or look at any examples/tutorials? Please try this yourself first, we won't just do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For code like

```
if(a==1) {do1();}
else if(a==2) {do2();}
else if(a==3) {do2();}
else if(a==4) {do2();}
else { doOther(); }
```

Equal code will be

```
switch(a) {
    case 1: 
        do1();
        break;
    case 2: 
        do2();
        break;
    case 3: 
        do3();
        break;
    case 4: 
        do4();
        break;
    default:
        doOther();
        break;
 }
```

Comment: As shown by @mare92's [most recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830317/java-draw-flowers-using-stddraw), all this spoon-feeding answer is doing is to teach the original poster how to beg and not think for himself or try for himself. Please consider this when answering future such questions, questions that show no effort whatsoever.